# firebase deploy hangs without error (firebase tools 3.17.2)

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

I am attempting to deploy a firebase hosting project and I find it hangs and never progresses.  The project has just been created with `firebase init` and only contains the `index.html` and `404.html` files within the public folder.

The debug output from the command is

```
    C:\VSProjects\wearable>firebase deploy  --debug
    [2018-01-30T12:34:39.086Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    [2018-01-30T12:34:39.093Z] CLI Version:   3.17.2
    [2018-01-30T12:34:39.093Z] Platform:      win32
    [2018-01-30T12:34:39.095Z] Node Version:  v9.4.0
    [2018-01-30T12:34:39.103Z] Time:          Tue Jan 30 2018 23:34:39 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)
    [2018-01-30T12:34:39.103Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    [2018-01-30T12:34:39.129Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
    [2018-01-30T12:34:39.130Z] > authorizing via signed-in user
    [2018-01-30T12:34:39.134Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/projects/[project hidden]

    Tue Jan 30 2018 23:34:39 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)
    [2018-01-30T12:34:40.002Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 server=nginx, date=Tue, 30 Jan 2018 12:34:40 GMT, content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, content-length=111, connection=close, x-content-type-options=nosniff, strict-transport-security=max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains, cache-control=no-cache, no-store, via=HTTP/1.1 proxy10730
    [2018-01-30T12:34:40.005Z] >>> HTTP REQUEST GET https://admin.firebase.com/v1/database/[project hidden]/tokens

    Tue Jan 30 2018 23:34:40 GMT+1100 (AUS Eastern Daylight Time)
    [2018-01-30T12:34:41.275Z] <<< HTTP RESPONSE 200 server=nginx, date=Tue, 30 Jan 2018 12:34:41 GMT, content-type=application/json; charset=utf-8, content-length=263, connection=close, x-content-type-options=nosniff, strict-transport-security=max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains, cache-control=no-cache, no-store, via=HTTP/1.1 proxy10730
```

I have attempted the following:
a) Logout and login
b) return firebase tools 3.17.2
c) Node 9.3.0

Any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please contact Firebase support.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/